# Assign multiple Variables at once as result from Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Due to runtime I want to asign the columns of a single-row-resultset to multiple variables at once in a SQL-Server stored Procedure. I want to replace the last 2 lines of the following code:

```
Declare @A int
Declare @B int
Select @A = (Select Col1 From Table1 Where ID=1234)
Select @B = (Select Col2 From Table1 Where ID=1234)
```

Since in this version the program would search twice for the ID=1234 i want to do something like

```
Select @A, @B = (Select Col1, Col2 From Table1 Where ID=1234)
```

But i can't figure out the correct syntax for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this

```
Select @A =Col1,@B=Col2  From Table1 Where ID=1234
```

Answer (score 3):

Just comma separate them and have the assignments directly in the `SELECT` rather than using a subquery:

```
Select @A = Col1,@B =  Col2 From Table1 Where ID=1234
```

See [`select @local_variable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx):

```
SELECT { @local_variable { = | += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression } [ ,...n ] [ ; ]
```

Where the `[,...n]` means you can repeat the preceding part as many times as you want to, separating each repeat with a comma.

Answer (score 2):

For separate assignment statement, you need to use `SET`

```
DECLARE @A INT
DECLARE @B INT
SET @A = (SELECT Col1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1234)
SET @B = (SELECT Col2 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1234)
```

For single assignment statement, you can use

```
SELECT @A = Col1, @B = Col2 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1234
```

Answer (score -2):

You will want to use a **cursor** for iterating over the data set, even if it contains only one row. See http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-a-simple-example-using-a-cursor/